# How do you determine the content that is used when someone shares from a mobile device?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ios-sharesheet

When a user is at a website on a mobile device and decides to share the link using the built-in share feature, how do you determine what value is used for the share content?

[image: screenshot of website with share popup]

[image: screenshot of twitter post form]

As you can see, it just pulls the title of the website when you share to Twitter for example.

You can change it, but is there a way to determine what is populated so it doesn't just pull in the title automatically?

I do have all of the meta tags set up on the page for stuff like Twitter cards and all that. I am just not sure how to control this.

Answer (score 0):

These are controlled by the activityItems you pass on to a UIActivityViewController..

You should find more details in the below links

The official documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Built_in_Activity_Types)

Brilliant Mattt Thompson has a write up on this [here](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/)